# CSS styling of <ul> is not working in external sheet but internally works

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have a kind of weird problem with  CSS styling. This style is not working although other styles in the same sheet works. I checked the path of external sheet and it was ok, then I put ul {} styling code into  in internal sheet and it also worked fine.

```
This is html code: 

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang= "cs-cz">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Mr. Chapadlákovo podvodní království</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/layout.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/textstyle.css">
</head>
<body>
 <!--NAVBAR-->   
<ul>
  <li><a href="#Lorem" id="fontNavbar">Království</a></li>
  <li><a href="#lorem" id="fontNavbar">LOREM</a></li>
  <li><a href="#lorem" id="fontNavbar">LOREM</a></li>
  <li><a href="#lorem" id="fontNavbar">LOREM</a></li>
  <li><a href="#lorem" id="fontNavbar">LOREM</a></li>
  <li><a href="#Kontakt" id="fontNavbar">Kontakt</a></li>
</ul>
</body>
```

I cut it to the maximum to see if anything collides:

```
body {
  background-color: rgb(20, 20, 20);
  background-attachment: scroll;
};

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
};

li a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 7vw;
};
```

Comment: caching issue maybe, or u have other styles overriding it (you are targeting pretty wide with ul)? you can chec pretty easy in devtools in case they are overriden or just not applied at all.

Answer (score 0):

remove ";" in css file

```
body {
  background-color: rgb(20, 20, 20);
  background-attachment: scroll;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

li a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 7vw;
}
```

Comment: thank you! It was caused by this. Now I feel really stupid. :D